# Differences between coverage test tools for ES6/Babel/Mocha

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, code-coverage, babeljs

I am looking into implement a Testing Coverage Tool in my web app that uses ES6, Babel and Mocha. I encountered three main tools which are:

- [Adana](https://github.com/adana-coverage) (babel-plugin-transform-adana)
- [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul) (babel-istanbul)
- [Isparta](https://github.com/douglasduteil/isparta)

Given that no tool is better than the other and I am not asking for suggestion of which is better, my question is:

is there any important difference between these tools that I should take into consideration when choosing a Testing Coverage Tool for an app that implements ES6, Babel and Mocha? I researched a lot on the topic but cannot find a lot of orientation.

Also, is there any major tool I should be looking at that I am missing? Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to use karma to run your tests. It include Istanbul by default. isparta seem to run on istanbul too. I don't know Adana but it description is "Instrument JavaScript. Like Istanbul." So probably Istanbul is a good choice to start.